# Parallel thread processing in C#

Tags: c#, task

I am working on one heavy thread based processing, and each Task get its turn only after 10 sec. I was looking to enhance the performance, so need some suggestion, how to improve below codebase.

```
public void StartAllListerner()
{
     foreach (tblUserMaster item in tblUserMasterBL.Instance.GetMany(new dbEntities()))
      {
          StartListenerProcess(item.ShoretelUserId, item.UserDN);
      }       
}

public void StartListenerProcess()
{
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        TrackIncomingRequest();
    });
}

public void TrackIncomingRequest()
{
    do
    {
        if(current thread gets event) 
        {   
            foreach(var item in allEvents)
            {
                 // Some unending heavy activity, which is running continuously in background
            }
        }
    } while (true);
}
```

Based on current codebase, processing happens only when thread gets some event, else its just continuously wait for event to occur.

So, how can we run parallel Task in C#?

Comment: Why do you need to parallelize the _creation_ of tasks? If you're after the partitioner used by `Parallel.ForEach`, using it directly would be a bit clearer.

Comment: I would suggest asking this question on the Code Review stack exchange: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ this is where you can ask people how to best optimise your code :)

Comment: Why are you using `Task.Run` in `StartListenerProcess`? `Parallel.ForEach` has already given it a thread. Do you really need to a new `Task` again?

Comment: Based on the code provided, I'm guessing you're using busy wait. It will not scale well; you're keeping the thread busy sitting and doing nothing. Instead use any signalling constructs like `WaitHandle`. or [async versions of waithandle by stephen toub](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/02/11/building-async-coordination-primitives-part-2-asyncautoresetevent/)

Comment: @smoksnes, even worse: `Parallel.ForEach` is not guaranteed to give it a thread. It is allowed to wait for one of the tasks to finish before it starts another one.

Comment: Please explain the *actual* problem, not your attempt to solve it. Mixing Task.Run and Parallel.ForEach is definitely wrong. You can convert events to tasks using eg `FromAsync` or the TaskCompletionSource class. You could also use a queue or an ActionBlock. It's impossible to pick one option though without knowing the problem

Comment: @Haukinger & smoksness : I was trying multiple things, so missed to remove Parallel.ForEach, i have just updated my original approach.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos : looking to speed up the processing, based on current load each thread executes after 10 sec. Wanted to perform some activity where multiple threads can run at a time, in a parallel manager and not sequential

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
public void TrackIncomingRequest()
{
    do
    {
        if(current thread gets event) 
        {   
            Parallel.Foreach(allEvents, (item) =>
            {
               // Some unending heavy activity, which is running continuously in background
            });
        }
    } while (true);
}
```